# Центровать картинку внутри div'а?

Tags: css, изображения, width

Есть картинка, у которой ширина больше родительского div'a (overflow: hidden;). Как сделать так, чтобы видна была только центральная часть картинки, с сохранением пропорций картинки, при уменьшении ширины div'а и чтоб при этом картинка занимала всю высоту div'а?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Вариант 1: сделать картинку ширины `div`

```css
.div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
}
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="div">
    <img src="https://mobidevices.ru/images/2017/02/iPhone-7.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

#### Вариант 2: сделать картинку `background` к `div`

```css
.div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    background: url("https://mobidevices.ru/images/2017/02/iPhone-7.jpg") no-repeat 50% / contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="div"></div>
```

Comment: Да, как вариант) Спасибо! Только мне надо бы именно саму картинку, а не в качестве фонового рисунка.

Comment: @gais.05 доработал

Comment: воспользовался таки background'ом спасибо!)

Answer (score 2):

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  margin: 15vh auto auto auto;
  width: 40vw;
  height: 70vh;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://mobidevices.ru/images/2017/02/iPhone-7.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо! решил таки сделать фон. рисунком, получилось ) background-size: cover;
 background-position: center bottom;